# Trying to use $_GET in PHP

Tags: php, get

I made this simple radio group below but I'm having some difficulty calling it in PHP.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="get" action="pre_process.php">
    <p>
      <input name="q" type="text" size="80"/>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" id="search_button" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="SearchFormat" value="0" id="SearchFormat_0" />
        Agreggated</label>
      <br />
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="SearchFormat" value="1" id="SearchFormat_1" />
        Non-Aggregated</label>
```

I'm using the following code but I get an error of undefined index: SearchFormat

```
if($_GET["SearchFormat"]==0)
{
    do stuff...
```

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: try var_dump($_GET) to actually see everything its submitted with GET method

Comment: How does your form tag look? I have a feeling that you are using the POST method. In this case you should access the field by using $_POST['SearchFormat'].

Comment: If you expect to find the values in `$_GET` then make sure you set the form's `method` attribute to `get`: `<form method="get">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just see at your browser, May be there is possibility that you are running your code by direct from folder . But you have to run your page with localhost address.
Look at the code below.
This is First PHP file: radio.php

```
    <html>
   <body>
   <form action="test1.php" method="get">
  <label>
 <input type="radio" name="SearchFormat" value="0"  />
Agreggated</label>  <br />

 <label>
<input type="radio" name="SearchFormat" value="1"  />
Non-Aggregated</label>
<input type="Submit" name="btn" value="SearchFormat" />
```

Now another PHP file is:test1.php

```
 <?php   
 if($_GET['SearchFormat']==0)
   {
   echo "I ma checked";
   }
else  
   {
   echo "I am not checked";
   }
 ?>
```

You have to run this PHP file by writing localhost/radio.php at the browser.
Second php file than automatically runs as you click on SearchFormat button.

And also one thing you have to save your all php page in WAMP/XAMP folder.

Answer (score 1):

checkboxes and radio buttons are only available in your $_GET or $_POST if they've been checked
you need to use something like 'isset()':

```
if(isset($_GET["SearchFormat"]) ){
    // checkbox was checked
}
```

to check the value

Answer (score 1):

try this instead

```
if(isset($_GET['SearchFormat']) {
    //code......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox will only exist if it is checked. Best way to do this with radiobuttons would be to have at least one checked by default.

```
<input type="radio" name="SearchFormat" value="0" id="SearchFormat_0" checked="checked"/>
```

Also check it in the php script with the isset() function.

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone, got it sorted!